Is that right that about trace of the two density matrices multiply to each other?
We have:
$$\mathrm{Tr}\,(\rho \rho^{\prime})=1$$
then, is it right to say $\rho=\rho^{\prime}$?

What have you tried? Consider to rephrase the question in a little nicer way (also the title)...

Hint: Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for the Hilbert-Schmidt/Frobenius inner product.

Added
I see this was essentially @Tobias Fünke comment which I didn't see.
End
Given the Hilbert-Schmidt scalar product you realize that
$$\mathrm{Tr}\,(\rho \rho^{\prime}) = \langle \rho, \rho' \rangle_{HS}. 
$$
Being a scalar product it satisfies Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. But the 2-norm of a density matrix is necessarily smaller or equal to one. And it is one only for pure states. The maximum of the Cauchy-Schwarz is attained only for parallel vector $\rho=\lambda \rho'$. But the condition of being density matrices fixes $\lambda=1$.
So one can have
$$\mathrm{Tr}\,(\rho \rho^{\prime}) = 1,$$
only for $\rho=\rho'=$ a pure state.

...see my comment...

Absolutely. I didn't see that before.

Another way of seeing this (in contrast to the more formal @lcv's answer) is considering a one qubit density matrix parametrized by a Bloch vector $(s_x,s_y,s_z)$ and
$$
\rho = \dfrac{\mathbb{1} + \vec{s}\cdot\vec{\sigma}}{2},
$$
so you can see that
$$
\text{Tr}(\rho_1 \rho_2) = \dfrac{1 + \vec{s}_1\cdot\vec{s}_2}{2},
$$
which is only $1$ if $\vec{s}_1=\vec{s}_2$, ergo, $\rho_1 = \rho_2$.
The same holds if you consider more qubits, with the only caveat that now you will also need $\rho$ to be pure for this to hold, as for mixed states $\text{Tr}\, \rho^2 <1$.

I think you've introduced a MathJax error with your recent edit (?). Anyway, if I am not mistaken, your answer is simply a special case of the more general fact I've indicated in my comment. Indeed, the Pauli matrices +Identity build an orthogonal basis with respect to the Hilbert Schmidt inner product (in the space of bounded linear operators on $\mathbb C^2$, which results in the decomposition you've written.

Yeah, definitely! I just wanted to give a more concrete/less abstract example, that can help to build up intuition. What you proposed is of course a way better answer for the general n-qubit case (basically because mine doesn't hold up with more than one qubit).

For pure states, given the condition, it is right to say $ \rho = \rho' $. Mixed states however require checking their respective eigenvalues and eigenvectors to see if they overlap.

For a mixed state, we would have $\text{Tr} \rho^2 <1$, so it is not possible to have $\rho=\rho'$.

Also, could you prove why this is the case for pure states?
